# ScrollView addSubview: very slow

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I am using a scrollview to display a viewcontrollers view. if the user reaches the end of the cached views my method reloads the new views. My NSLogs say that the method is finished but it takes additional 5 seconds to display the view.
I think that the [scrollView addSubview:vc.view] is very very slow but I found nothing to improve it.

the whole method gets called in -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

```
 scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake((320.f*index)+135.f, 151, 50, 50)];
    [activityIndicator setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [scrollView addSubview:activityIndicator];

    MBBAppDelegate *delegate = (MBBAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    [delegate fetchDealsWithFilter:dealFilter fromIndex:index toIndex:(index+3) onSuccess:^(id object){

        MBBDealList *list = object;

        int i = 0;

        ProductDetailViewController *vc;

        for (MBBDeal *deal in [list deals]) {

            NSLog(@"start %i",i);
            int indexInArray = i;//[list.deals indexOfObject:deal];

            if (indexInArray+index >= numDeals) {
                return;
            }

            vc = [[ProductDetailViewController alloc] init];

            //fetch the deal and insert
            vc.numberOfDeals = numDeals;
            vc.dealIndex = index+1+indexInArray;
            vc.dealFilter = dealFilter;
            vc.deal = deal;

            vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(320.f*(index+indexInArray), 0.f, 320.f, 436.f);

            [scrollView addSubview:vc.view];

            [productDetailViewControllers insertObject:vc atIndex:(index+indexInArray)];

            i++;
        }
        [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }];

}
```

Does anyone know how I can improve my method?

Comment: When you profiled the app with Instruments, where did you find most of the time was being spent during those 5 seconds?

Comment: which preset should I use in Instruments? I found nothing helpful.

Comment: this delay is because of data fetch process......

Comment: you can write your data fetch process in background thread once data fetch is completed update your UI,or write your data fetch process in ViewDidAppear method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can understand from your problem is that, the activity indicator that you have used to show the data fetch process is not used properly.
You data fetch process is still working, even after the activity indicator disappears.

You can do 2 things for that:
ether call the data fetch method in background using performSelectorInBackground method or place the activity indicator in the app delegate where you have created your data fetch method.

Comment: I edited my method and do the reload with performSelectorInBackground and it takes half a second to reload (says NSLog) but the view is still presented after a delay. Maybe the addSubview: method is not the fastest way? I have a ViewController that contains the scrollview and the reloadMethod is located in it, so doing the ActivityIndicator stuff in the appdelegate isn't a option?!

Comment: I did another measurement one time it took 7 seconds, 8 seconds and another time 17 seconds, but I can't find the reason.

Comment: the view delays when you write the data fetch method in the "ViewDidLoad" function. The view can be loaded faster if you fetch the data in "ViewDidAppear" function